# JQuery animate({scrolltop: top}, 800) is not smooth in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, jquery-animate, smoothing

I am trying to use smooth scrolling between section on my site.

I have tried manually scrolling as well by running `$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 2000 }, 800);` from the console.

Everything works good on firefox, but on chrome and edge it is not smooth. It will start out slow as if it is going to take a full minute to get to the proper section. Then just before it should be done (~800 ms) it will jump much faster. It will still go to the proper place.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer provided [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62509847/2103688). This didn't work for me though because I want the user to be able to scroll if they want to. Here is the css work around I am using:

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%; }
body { overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%;}
```

I'm just forcing the body to be scrolled instead of the html. I'm not sure why chrome and edge are breaking without this, it might be something to do with an extension I'm using or a smooth-scroll setting that I don't realize I'm using.